# Trying to use MySQL Database instead of H2 to retrieve Process Info [in AS7]--jbpm-console NOT being deployed

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jboss, h2, jbpm

This has been a very frustrating few days trying to get this to work.  In trying to get failed processes restarted, I was not able to retrieve process instance information from the H2 tables which hold the data.  I've decided to use another DBMS to which I have access to--MySQL.

I've configured my package to use a MySQL database instead of the default in-memory database to record process info data.  I've followed a few examples to get the point where I am now.  The main documentation I'm using is

https://zorq.net/b/2011/07/12/adding-a-mysql-datasource-to-jboss-as-7/#comments
+
https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationinAS7#Installing_a_JDBC_driver_as_a_deploymentI

I have

1.) Downloaded the MySQL driver from dev.mysql.com, and realized after DAYS of trying to get it to work that it was JDBC-4 compliant and it had to be manipulated in order for it to work
2.)  Installed the driver as a module by creating the module file in jboss/modules/com/mysql/main:

```
 <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql">
         <resources>
                <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin_COMPLIANT.jar"/>
         </resources>
         <dependencies>
                 <module name="javax.api"/>
                 <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
          </dependencies>
 </module>
```

3.) Defined the datasource in the standalone configuration jboss/standalone/configuration/standalone-full.xml:

```
   <datasources>
            <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/jbpmDS" pool-name="jbpmDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jbpm6</connection-url>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>root</user-name>
                    <password>pass</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
```

5.) The JBPM DB has also been created with the scripts provided in jbpm-installer/db/ddl-scripts/mysql.  All of the persistence tables seem to be there.

I'm launching AS7 with  . jboss/bin/standalone.sh --server-config=standalone-full.xml&

This installation has not been successful and I think this (recurring) exception is preventing my jbpm-console from being launched:
 
`11:52:46,592 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (MSC service thread 1-12) HHH000319: Could not get database metadata: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'sequences' in information_schema
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:372)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2531)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2489)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1446)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedStatement.java:340)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.initSequences(DatabaseMetadata.java:149) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.(DatabaseMetadata.java:70) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.(DatabaseMetadata.java:63) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:196) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:178) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:457) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]`

Comment: Hi there, is that the complete stack trace? I don't see anything jBPM related there. I googled the issue, and it seems related with the dialect that you are using.. it seems that you need to use the INNODB dialect to work with MYSQL -> http://www.jspresso.org/forum/help-problem-connect-database-when-run-swing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links you posted only help you set up your datasource but you also need to change the persistence configuration for hibernate from H2 to MySQL.

The official jbpm documentation has a section for that:
http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.2/userguide/jBPMInstaller.html#d0e950

Comment: Thanks you!  I indeed missed this step --> 3.6.3.3. Configuration.  Updating this file --jbpm-installer/db/jbpm-persistence-JPA2.xml-- and then reinstalling the AS7 package did it.  I hope it works this well in WildFly!  ;-)  I'm stuck here now -->Caused by: bitronix.tm.utils.PropertyException: no writeable property 'URL' in class 'bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.lrc.LrcXADataSource'